# Gzip compress offline?

Tags: apache, htaccess, gzip

I've configured my site to serve compressed content by putting this line in .htaccess

```
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/javascript text/css application/javascript application/json
```

This works perfectly for almost all files except a few large JSON files that are above 200Kb. For some reason they are not being compressed. I see that they don't using the net tab in firebug and the Network section in chrome.

So as a workaround I thought I could compress these files offline and have Apache read them compressed.
What tool should I use to compress them? is the linux gzip the one? any special flags or something I should use?
What should I put in .htaccess so that the server would know to serve these files with content-encoding gzip ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, use gzip to compress the file. You'll save a little of CPU power.

```
gzip -c your_big_json_file > your_big_json_file.gz
```

Then in your Apache configuration enable Multiviews

```
Options MultiViews
```

it does [content-negotiation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/content-negotiation.html) with the browser.

Note: change the reference to your json file in the code to use the newly created `.gz` file!