# how to best enable gzip compression on shared hosting

Tags: php, htaccess, gzip

I must assume that this is a duplicate question, but I could not find the answer myself.
I want to enable gzip compression to everything my website sends (mostly php, css, a slight bit of js).

[this question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/9995/gzip-compress-offline) makes a point of adding a line into the .htaccess file (that i do have access to) but i'm not sure if that would include the dynamic content.

[this question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/10311/can-i-enable-gzip-on-godaddy) (has a typo in the question, it should be ob_start I think) tells me how to enable gzip to php files. and after fixing the typo it seems to work.

do i need to use both ? is there anything else i need as well ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output of PHP files is HTML. That HTML will be compressed using [the code in this question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/9995/gzip-compress-offline):

```
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/javascript text/css application/javascript application/json
```

That's all you need to do (assuming mod_deflate is enabled for Apache).